# Display User name in Output Field and Output text

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:outputField value="{!application.CreatedById}" 
                  style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color="grey"/>

<apex:outputText value="{!application.CreatedById}" 
                 style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color="grey"/>
```

This both is giving me different value. Output Field is showing name and outputtext is showing id. 
I want to use output text to show name. Is it possible... as i have to add styling to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<apex:outputText value="{!application.CreatedBy.name}" 
                 style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color="grey"/>
```

Uses the relationship to bring back the name

Comment: Its giving save error. Extra ',' .. Do in need to change some thing in controller code

Comment: @TestNS just use `.` instead of `,`: `application.CreatedBy.name`

Comment: It worked thanks.... Done one more change in controller code ... i was missing CreactedBy.Name in Query.. Added that as well